# SSH login behaviour using passphrase or password

Tags: ssh, public-key, private-key

What is the correct behavior of SSH when it comes to authentication on SSH login? Is it passphrase prompt and password prompt? Or is it passphrase only? Because in my setup i have tried all but i do not know what is the correct and proper setup

Comment: Expected behavior depends on what authentication methods are supported and/or required by the server or the client.  In a default configuration, both public-key and password authentication are permitted; the client will attempt public-key first, and failing that fall back to password.

Comment: What field should i configure on sshd_config to force it to use only passphrase and no fallback?

Comment: Passphrase being a  user:password scheme, in your ssh_config uncomment this line:  PubkeyAuthentication=no   if using on a case by case basis use ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@ip